# Multiply a raster list with a field value list in a FOR loop in ArcPy

Tags: raster, arcgis-10.1, arcpy, loop, list

I'm trying to create a simple map algebra calculation not managed by ModelBuilder, but writing it in Python is trickier than I thought.
I have a list of raster in a GDB and I must multiply them by each value contained in a population field.
I created my raster list, the a search cursor for the population value, and I use everything in 2 nested FOR loop to do my multiplication.

```
# Import arcpy module
import arcpy
from arcpy import env
from arcpy.sa import *

#Check Spatial Analyst extension
arcpy.CheckOutExtension("Spatial")

# Set the current workspace to iterate on rasters
arcpy.env.workspace = "D:/PROJECTS/03_2014_AB_HYDRO_MODELLING/02_TRANSFORM_DATA/WPWFS/WaterSupplyVulnerability.gdb"

#Variables
PiS = "D:/PROJECTS/03_2014_AB_HYDRO_MODELLING/02_TRANSFORM_DATA/WPWFS/SurfaceWaterUtilities.gdb/SurfaceWaterNetwork/SurfUtsAB_Proj_corr25m" # Water treatment station feature class
Pi = ["POPN_CURRE"] # Get the population value in the field "POPN_CURRE" for each water treatment station
WiS = arcpy.ListRasters("WEI*", "All") # Create a list of rasters
Qn = arcpy.Raster('WaterYield_CubicMeters_SqKm_Year') # Water yield raster

#  For each Station's population Pi in All stations PiS, multiply POPN_CURRE with rasts (119 rasters)
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(PiS, Pi) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        row.next()
        for Wi in WiS:
            print Wi
            WiPi = Wi * row
            WiPi.save("D:/PROJECTS/03_2014_AB_HYDRO_MODELLING/02_TRANSFORM_DATA/WPWFS/WaterSupplyVulnerability.gdb/WiPi" + row)
            WiPiS = arcpy.ListRasters("Wi*", "All") # Create a list to iterate through WiPi calculation rasters
            SWiPi = CellStatistics("WiPiS", "SUM", "DATA")
            SWiPi.save("D:/PROJECTS/03_2014_AB_HYDRO_MODELLING/02_TRANSFORM_DATA/WPWFS/WaterSupplyVulnerability.gdb/SWiPi" + row)
            IMPn = Qn * SWiPi
            IMPn.save("D:/PROJECTS/03_2014_AB_HYDRO_MODELLING/02_TRANSFORM_DATA/WPWFS/WaterSupplyVulnerability.gdb/IMPn" + row)
        arcpy.Delete_management(WiPiS) #Delete intermediate raster from Times processing
```

It returns the following error :
Runtime error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 4, in <module>
TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'tuple'
```

I understand that my population field is not a integer, and so ?
When I try the 2 for loop with just a print rather than the calculation, it works. 
So what is the function or method to call ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

When you create a data access cursor object, the rows are returned as tuples with a length equal to the number of columns in the feature (or the fields specified when creating the cursor). In the line where you are calculating `WiPi = Wi * row` you need to call the desired tuple value by using `row[0]`. In your case there is only 1 value in the tuple, but you still need to index the row object to get that value.

You will also need to create a raster object for each raster in the list your are iterating over. You can do this simply by using the Raster() command of the arcpy.sa module:

`WiPi = Raster(Wi) * row`

Additionally, the `row.next()` command is superfluous in this context. Because the rows returned by the data access style cursor are tuple objects, the `row.next()` command is actually returning the next value of the row tuple. You aren't assigning the value to any variable so as-is the line does not do anything. It's not hurting anything, but just for the sake of cleaner code you can remove this line.